# Appending two data frames using R

Tags: r

I have two data frames df1 and df2. I want to append all the rows of df2 into df1 in their respective columns. See the desired output.

```
df1<-data.frame("Marks 1"= c(1,2), "Marks 2"=c(5,6),"Marks 3"=c(1,2),"Marks 4"=c(7,8))
df2<-data.frame("Marks 2"= c(7,8), "Marks 3"=c(3,4))
```

[Desired Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sxc0C.jpg)

Comment: `dplyr::bind_rows(df1, df2)`

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for this?

```
library(dplyr)
df1<-data.frame("Marks 1"= c(1,2), "Marks 2"=c(5,6),"Marks 3"=c(1,2),"Marks 4"=c(7,8))
df2<-data.frame("Marks 2"= c(7,8), "Marks 3"=c(3,4))

full_join(df1, df2) # option 1

bind_rows(df1, df2) # option 2
```

Comment: ya thanks a lot. I am pretty new to this.